# PHP Toolkit Search Multiple Fields

Tags: soap-api, soap, search, php-toolkit

Is it possible to search multiple fields?

I am using the query:

```
$search = 'FIND {'.$email.'} IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING CONTACT(ID)';
$response = $mySforceConnection->search($search);
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
$search = 'FIND {'.$email.', '.$firstname.'} IN EMAIL,NAME FIELDS RETURNING CONTACT(ID)';
$response = $mySforceConnection->search($search);
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to apply a [SOSL where condition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) if you had an exact email match. But I don't think the [Find {SearchQuery}](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm#topic-title) will span fields.

Otherwise you might find a directly [SOQL search](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) to be an easier approach if you know you are just searching for the email address and name.

Comment: So I can basically add the condition in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @odedta Yes, a standard SOQL where clause can handle these conditions.